# How to test Hbase Get using Mocha/Node.js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, hbase

Hi guys I have a job that has a method that extracts data from HBase given a key in Node.js, something like follows:

```
findHbaseData(field1, field2) {
  const key = generateKey(field1, field2);
  const data = hbase.get(key);
  data['field3'] = data.field3.toUpperCase;
  return data
}
```

The Hbase.get works like follows:

```
const HBaseRestClient = require('hbase');
const {Connection} = HBaseRestClient

this.client = HBaseRestClient(
    this.confHbase // Here I have table name, host and port
);

this.table = this.confHbase.table;

async get(id, columns) {
    
    let schema = this.getSchema(columns)
    return await new Promise( (res, rej) => {
      const row = this.client.table(this.table).row(id);

      if (row) {

        let convert = (err, values, response) => {
          if (err) {
            rej(err);
            return;
          }

          const innerModel = Object.create(this.model);

          const result = this.convertRow(values, innerModel, schema, columns);
          res(result);
        }

        if (columns && columns.length) {
          let hbaseColumns = this.schemaToHbaseColumns(columns)

          row.get(hbaseColumns, convert);
        } else {
          row.get(convert);
        }

      }
    } );
  }
```

I need to test this method (findHbaseData) using mocha or chai but my environment test (Jenkins) can't access the Hbase, it's possible to use mocha to simulate this access and return fake data, instead to run the real `hBase.get(key)`?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the minimal, complete code? where does the `hbase` come from?

Comment: Hello I'm sorry, I tried to short the code thinking it will simplify but this hbase.get is a method that uses hbase package, I will post the code as an answer here because it's too long.

Comment: I just edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the answer.
I could create a `HBaseRestClient.prototype.get(id,columns)` and read the data from a json file.